# Does multi storage pools make sense to avoid more damage from a bad disk?

Tags: raid, nas, software-raid, synology

I am a beginner of NAS(and its hardwares), and I get some basic knowledge about RAID from Synology's guidebook. There are many tutorials taught me how to use my hard drive devices to create the storage pool. But I'm not sure about the sense of creating multi pools with different RAID array mode.

**My devices:**

- 6 bays DS918+ DIY NAS. No extra bays.
- 6 * 8TB HHD, and I installed Synology DSM7.1 on one of them. The storage space is more than enough so I will never buy more bigger or smaller disks. If any of the 6 ones is damaged, I just want to buy a same one to replace.

**My demands:**

1. Store videos, less than 20TB. There will be infrequent write operations, that means I will save movies, and watch them again and again in weekends. I don' t care about speed, but often worry about how troublesome it will be when any disk dead. It is ok for me to download some of the movies again, but I don' t want to lose all of them at the same time.
2. Store photos and documents and snapshots, less than 4TB. This is usually considered as "important files", so I have already save copies in my PC, mobile HDD and cloud storage before I start using NAS.

**Considering these two demands, I can accept the loss of some data when a disk damaged, but want to make sure it won' t break other disks and cause more damage.**

As far as i understand(of course could be completely wrong), **Basic**, **RAID1**, or **RAID5** might come in handy for my demands. But there is a saying that another disk may damage too after the first disk dead when rebuilding RAID5.

What really confused me is that, **will it be better for me to create a storage pool for demand1 and another pool for demand2, comparing with an only pool for two demands together**? If so, or not, which array mode is suitable for my requirement?

I wrote this question with the help of Google translate so welcome to edit if there are incorrect terms.

Comment: What do you mean by snaphots?  (that word has a specific meaning with respect of disk management, and may entirely change the nature if the question)

Comment: @davidgo Emmmm....something like time machine in Mac?

Comment: If you don't use use any kind of RAID for the movies, you may lose 8 TB of them if a disk fails, and this is far beyond "It is ok for me to download some of the movies again". So, RAID is needed. Keep it simple and use the same RAID array for the movies, the photos, etc...

Comment: @Krahmal A Time Machine backup on a NAS a not a "snapshot". BTW, besides being hooribly slow, Time Machine on a network drive is something quite unreliable, I do not recommend it at all.

Comment: @PierU Well, one pool of RAID score one more point. And If I mean the time machine of Windows PC, which word is better?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "time machine of Windows PC"...

Comment: To clarify my understanding of @PierU comments - If you dont use RAID **or similar** (jbid, lvm, shm are all sort-of raid like) you will have multiple partitions and only loose data on 1 partition....

Comment: Also, while I understand what you are sating about time-machine like snapshots they don't change the nature of the question as its not instantaneous and are filesystem agnostic (Some filesystems/partition management systems do something similar but more powerful - eg zfs/lvm/btrfs but they work very differently and need to be taken into account when looking at partitioning)

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the best you can do is to create one pool with RAID6. Such array can survive failure of two disks. The available space will be 4*8 ~ 32TB. If you want to go crazy and can get your information in 24TB you can create above RAID6 with one spare disk. This will give you more time to react on failed disk.

Of course the performance will be lower than RAID5 or RAID1 but you should balance the speed and safety.

Comment: Thank you. "with one spare disk" -> Does this mean select 5 disks to create the pool and set that one as hot spare?

Comment: @Krahmal, correct. The array will be from 5 disks, RAID6 = 24TB available space + **hot** spare disk

Comment: And should the disk which installed DSM be in the RAID pool? Or it doesn' t matter?

Comment: @Krahmal, I am not familiar how Synology manage DSM. But you need to have 6 disks, 5 for RAID6 and one spare.

Comment: @Krahmal You don't have the choice where DSM is installed. AFAIK it is installed on all the disks (each time a new disk is enrolled, a hidden system partition is created, with a copy of DSM).

Comment: @PierU Thank you, I understand. The guidebook misled me. It says I can insert one disk into the machine to install DSM and then add the others.

Answer (score 0):

This is bordering on opinion based (and off-topic here but)

- Avoid RAID5 on 8tb disks.  There is some controversy but generally accepted wisdom is it should not be used on disks greater then 2tb.
- Be aware that RAID is not backup.  It prevents data loss in case if disk failure, but not accudental deletion, filesystem corruption, theft etc.
- Consider using a single RAID6 setup for all your data.  This will be simple to set up, gives you 32 tb of data and allows for up to 2 simultaneous disk failures.

This will give you better flexibility then RAID1 as well as more usable disk space and ease of use.

There may be other options (like SHR-2 and RAID10) but I would keep it simple and standards based here.

Comment: Thank you. I' ve heard these opinions. RAID6 scores one more point. Can we say in an array of RAID6, it is still possible for a second disk to damage caused by the first failure one, but the RAID6 just allowed two disks damaged together so it is ok?

Comment: @Krahmal - Yes - although the disks don't damage each other,  its just that (theoretically) the chances of disks dying around the same time - especially the same batch - is likely a little higher then people think - especially as RAID5/6 rebuilds can take a long time.  I tend to try either getting different makes of drives (or at least different batches) to mitigate this.